# Discord.py Member has specific role

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, user-roles

I want to check if a user who typed a command like %unban has the permissions to do that. My problem there is that I don't know how to do that.
I don't want to use the @command.has_role() Method. I want an if-else-clause where the code checks if the author has the role to print something like: "You have the permissions to do that" or "You don't have the permissions to do that".

```
@bot.command()
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
teamler = ctx.message.author.id
role = get(ctx.guild.roles, name='↬ Team Member')
banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#')

for ban_entry in banned_users:
    user = ban_entry.user

    if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
        await ctx.guild.unban(user)
        await ctx.send(f'Das {role.mention} ' + '<@' + f'{teamler}' + '>' + ' hat den Spieler ' + f'{user.mention}' + ' entbannt.')
```

Maybe you are able to solve my problem so the user can get a message if he has the permission / role to do something like %ban / %unban or not.

Comment: I don't deal with discord.py, but I like inspecting codes: you could just check how the `@command.has_role()` decorator looks like and see how they did it? ;P

Comment: Thanks a lot h4z3. This helped me a lot. Figured out how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with a simple if statement:

```py
# This will define the role you want them to have
role = client.get_role(roleid)

@bot.command()
async def unban(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if role in author.roles:
        try:
            await ctx.guild.unban(member)
            await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} has been unbanned!')
        except:
            await ctx.channel.send(f'{member.mention} is already unbanned!')
    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('You do not have the required role!')
```

This should check if the role is in their roles.

You can also use a has_permissions flag:

```py
@bot.command()
@bot.has_permissions(ban_members=True)
async def unban(ctx, member : discord.Member):
```